# Building AJAX Responses

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am building an unhandled exception handler for my AJAX callbacks but ran across a parameter I can not understand what it is. Through Fiddler I noticed that responses sent back from ASP.NET are built like so:

```
100|[__EVENTVALIDATION][__CALLBACKPARAM]
```

I know how to read the `__EVENTVALIDATION` and the `__CALLBACKPARAM`, but what is the `100|` and where is it being read from? If I don't include it in my responses they don't work. Here is my code:

```
//Check if the current request is an AJAX one
if (Context.Request["__CALLBACKID"] != null)
{
    Server.ClearError();

    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    Response.ContentType = "application/html";

    string response = "100|" + Context.Request["__EVENTVALIDATION"] + "There was an unhandled error.";

    Response.Write(response);
}
```

It works like this, but I want to read the `100|` from the server if possible and not hardcode it.

Thanks.

Edit: Here is a typical response with actual data:

```
100|/wEdAAMnRQqZXZxxCEF8iAQo1EbPVes4AfNrEwZQ25wFmngHn3SZ7wk+fYpRN1WwdwtMoysYtayZDybmykOphFidQUojFBJRRQ==success
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that this is the length of the response body / first parameter.